# How to save the Boolean value in sharedPreference also save the imageView

Tags: android

Please help me to resolve this problem...

Listner is here

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        AppListElement item = (AppListElement) mAdapter.getItem(position);
        if (item.isApp()) {
            mAdapter.toggle(item);

            showToastSingle(item.locked, item.title);
            // Update lock image
            view.findViewById(R.id.applist_item_image).setVisibility(item.locked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            // And the menu
            updateMenuLayout();

        }
    }
```

Here i am using boolean for Locked

```
public boolean locked = false;
```

I want to save the value of boolean in shared prefereance also the value of iamg. Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem is when i close the app and then open. i does not save the current instance value. if i need to unlock me should to double click on it...also the image visibility GONE

Comment: How are you saving ? Sharedpreference data will be cleared only then when you clear your app data or uninstall your application.

Comment: Are you searching for this? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: actually this is the question how i can save it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how you store a boolean in shared preference:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor= prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("lockedState", yourBooleanVariable);
editor.apply();
```

**This is how to access it again somewhere:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
boolean bool= prefs.getBoolean("lockedState", null);
```

***And what do you mean by value of img? Please Explain?***